# how to create a value in a column if the rows of the column have no spaces, and want to be spaced based on the value of the main column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with no spaces in the column like this:

for example

```
time          title
10:30         BridgeToTerabithia    
11:30         ManOnALedge
12:30         Memento
```

and I have the metadata for the actual movie title

for example

```
         title
        Bridge To Terabithia    
        Man On A Ledge
        Memento
```

how to be able to match the data in dataframe a with the metadata, so that the data title has the actual value according to the metadata
thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For match remove spaces:

```
df2['title'] = df2['title'].str.replace('\s+','')
```

Or add spaces after uppercase:

```
df1['title'] = df1['title'].replace('(?!^)(?=[A-Z])',' ',regex=True)
print (df)

    time                 title
0  10:30  Bridge To Terabithia
1  11:30        Man On A Ledge
2  12:30               Memento
```

Last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given any code on what you have tried, I will give a way to get you started with solving this problem: Remove spaces from the actual title and use that to find the title in the dataframe you want to fix (use a `df.merge` to join between two dfs and merge on the title without the space)

Comment: you could have put this as a comment instead

Comment: That's only a hint and too vague to constitute as a solution